# How do I convert SQL Server stored procedure with parameter to Oracle stored procedure with parameter?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

This would normally create a stored procedure in SQL Server Express but I'm not sure how I would re-write this in Oracle 11g as it doesn't take the "@" sign. Would anyone be able to convert this for me please?

```
create procedure search_expenses
   @startdate as datetime,
   @enddate as datetime
as
begin
   select 
       amount, description, trxdate, bankaccountid 
   from 
       expense 
   where 
       trxdate between @startdate and @enddate;
end
go
```

Comment: How long have you spent researching this? I bet I can find the answer in 5 minutes. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/create_procedure.htm

Comment: use swiss sql online converter, that may be help you

Comment: I tried converting it in Oracle and couldn't get it to work...kept saying I needed a INTO keyword...thanks for the negative votes...real helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Arun. John, thanks for the tutorial but it doesn't show an example of a select query within a stored procedure. Just inserts, updates and deletes which I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedures work differently in Oracle. You can't do a straight select that will output a result set for you. You need to Select into a `REFCURSOR` and your application will then have to handle that cursor.

Secondly, Parameters in Oracle is not specified with a `@`.

Here is an example of an Oracle Procedure

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_some_table(ref_cursor out sys_refcursor) is
  begin
    open ref_cursor for
      select * from my_schema.some_table;
  end get_some_table;
```

Comment: Thank you Jaques. That was the answer or at least the direction I was hoping for. I will have to read up on "refcursor" to convert it.